# Can I cast inside a sqlserver containsregex?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using an older PHP driver for mssql and am trying to filter out results using the ContainsRegExp command.  The issue is that the field I'm comparing is ntext and it causes the query to fail.  Is it possible to do a cast inside the ContainsRegExp command somthing like:

```
... AND Field1.ContainsRegExp(CAST(Field1 AS TEXT) AS Field1Test,\'html\')=1';
```

The full query statement:

```
'SELECT ReportID, ReportDate, CAST(ReportData AS TEXT) AS TextData FROM Database WHERE ReportData.ContainsRegExp(CAST(ReportData AS TEXT),\'html\')=1';
```

The error I see is:

```
message: Cannot call methods on ntext. (severity 15)
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  it might also help to remove the naming of the column.

Comment: hmm...I just did and it still complains about NTEXT

Comment: can we see a little more code and the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you try casting to `nvarchar(max)` instead (or to `nvarchar(4000)` if you are on SQL Server 2000–)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContainsRegExp is not a standard SQL Server command. So I'm not really sure how you've arrived at that statement, but it's not T-SQL.

My guess is that somewhere along the line a similar command has been used with a CLR type - because the syntax you are using (`Field.Operation()`) is used for calling methods on CLR types.